# How could i keep my $_GET params on laravel Redirect?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

I try to redirect by using,

```
  return redirect('/customer/' . $cust_id)->with('page',2);
```

**My Route is**,

```
 /customer/{id}
```

In Customer page, i use pagination.

So i need to redirect to the same page as it comes.

But how could i pass my get param with "**redirect()**"

**Actual URL**,

```
 http://domain.com/customer/2?page=3   // page=>3
```

I need to send back the control to the same page.

Is there any solution ?

Or Is it correct way to approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if it's set, otherwise not redirect using the item.

Your code will be:

```
return redirect()->back();
```

Or with notification you could do:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'This is my message!');
```

Comment: No, i cant get my "page" param, and it just redirect to the initial page. $_GET param where Flushed !

Comment: Therefor you can use redirect()->back(), that will work. I updated my code!

Comment: Using `redirect()->back()` is bad practise while on GET request.. user can refresh and button will be useless, use `redirect()->back()` only on POST requests... (after update / store)

Comment: Yah, i use this on POST request.

Answer (score 4):

The native PHP function [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) could be handly if you've got several `GET` variables that may be differnet for each re-direct.

```
// check for GET variables and build query string
$get = count($_GET) ? ('?' . http_build_query($_GET)) : '';

// redirect
return redirect('/customer/'.$cust_id.$get));
```

I don't use Laravel so there may be better ways of doing this but it seems like a clean solution anyway.

Comment: Thank you !
But i cant receive data.

Comment: @Shankar Thiyagaraajan You mean you can't access your `GET` variables?

Comment: Yah...I cant receive my $_GET params, dont know why !!

Answer (score 1):

You can get parameters with `request()`

```
$page = request->has('page') ? '?page='.request()->page : '';

return redirect('/customer/'.$cust_id.$page);
```

But if you need to redirect back to the previous page, use this:

```
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: Its directly go back to the list page,

Comment: OK, but the value of $_GET parem not fetched, but URL changed to "http://domain/customer/2?page=".

Comment: It's strange. Try to use `request()->page` instead.

Comment: You wrote `request->page`, fix it.

Comment: I get no response from this.

Comment: This works fine for me...
   return Redirect::to($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Comment: Be careful, referrer could be overridden using `JS`.

Answer (score 1):

To do a redirect with all the current get parameters you could just use:

Assuming you are eg on page /customer/1?page=3

```
$get = count($_GET) ? ('?' . http_build_query($_GET)) : ''; // Taken from @steve
$cust_id = 2
return redirect()->to('/customer/' . $cust_id . $get);
// will redirect you to /customer/2?page=3
```

If you have a **named route** like

```
Route::get('customer/{cust_id}', [CustomerController::class, 'getCustomer'])->name('customer.show');
```

it is even easier:

```
return redirect()
    ->route(
       'customer.show',
       ['cust_id' => $cust_id] + $_GET
);
// will redirect you to /customer/$cust_id?page=3
```

The **->with()** ist just for flashing variables. So those persist on the first view of the page. If you refresh this page, this session data is gone.